# How to get SOL for Solana Testnet?

Tags: testnet

How to receive or generate SOL for Solana Testnet (`testnet.solana.com`) for testing purposes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you're working locally, you need some SOL in order to send transactions. In non-mainnet environments you can receive SOL by airdropping it to your address

With the CLI you can run the airdrop command:

**Testnet**:

```
solana airdrop 1 --url testnet
```

**Devnet**:

```
solana airdrop 1 --url devnet
```

See the [Solana cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/local-development.html#getting-test-sol) on how to airdrop in other environments.

Comment: This assumes that the CLI tools are configured to point at testnet.  `--url testnet` can be passed with the above command to assert this

Answer (score 4):

for folks that don't have their CLI setup or just need devnet / testnet SOL at a moment's notice, https://solfaucet.com has an airdrop interface that you can access from your browser!

Answer (score 1):

There is also this one now https://faucet.solana.com that should be maintained.